# Why does my Oak sapling not want to grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason while playing minecraft, my saplings did not want to grow for 3 in-game days. To my surprise, while googling this question multiple times, I found no answer.

Why does this not work and how can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is underneath, above and beside the sapling? What kinda sapling is it? Did you try bonemeal? (And what game version)

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Trees need space and light to grow naturally. With bonemeal, the only requirement is space. IIRC the minecraft wiki has info on the exact space and light level requirements

Comment: We need a picture.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is enough space to grow. You can try to speed up the process if you put bone-meal on it.

**Edit:**
Thanks to George Willcox;
There are trees you can plant with four saplings (Jungle, spruce, and dark oak). They will also grow with just one.

Comment: Jungle, spruce, and dark oak can have four saplings, but they will also grow with just the one. This can be observed naturally, as one block wide trees of these varieties can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try breaking grass around it?

After you try this, use bone meal to fertilize it.